# Does there exist a 2d continuous phase transition that is first-order in mean-field theory and satisfies the Harris criterion $\nu>1$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

I am looking for an example of a clean, local $d=2$ classical model that undergoes a continuous phase transition on varying temperature that satisfies two properties:

1. The phase transition is resilient to quenched "energy"-like uncorrelated disorder (i.e. satisfies the Harris criterion that the critical exponent $\nu>1$).
2. If we turn up the dimension $d$ sufficiently high (or look at mean field theory), the clean phase transition is no longer continuous but becomes first-order.

Is there an example of a clean $d=2$ continuous transition satisfying the two properties above? I feel that there shouldn't be a theoretical impediment to such a model, but I'm having trouble coming up with examples satisfying both conditions.

---

For example, $q=3,4$ Potts models satisfy the second condition but not the first.

The Ising model marginally satisfies the first condition $\nu=1$, but clearly violates the second condition.

Comment: You actually mean $\nu>1$ by the Harris Criterion, right? Otherwise the $q=3$ Potts model will be perfect since it has $\nu=5/6$.

Comment: @Jun_Gitef17 Thanks, I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my answer fits to what you are looking for, but one example I can suggest is the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ lattice gauge theory which has the following Hamiltonian:
\begin{equation}
H=-\sum_{\langle i,j,k,l\rangle~\in~\square} \sigma_i\sigma_j\sigma_k\sigma_l
\end{equation}
where Ising spins $\sigma_i=\pm1$ are placed on the edges of the square lattice and the summation over $\square$ means for each square you have the four-body term. Higher dimensional extensions are defined through $d$-dimensional (hyper)cubic lattices, where you always stick to the squares for defining the terms.

In 2d, a Kramers-Wannier duality transformation reveals that this model is equivalent to the standard Ising model, therefore having $\nu=1$, which according to you marginally satisfies the first condition.

Now, what the "appropriate" mean-field theory/approximation for this model *should be* is debatable, but if we naively take the all-to-all connected model:
\begin{equation}
H=-\frac{1}{N^3}\sum_{i,j,k,l} \sigma_i\sigma_j\sigma_k\sigma_l 
= -N\Bigl(\frac{1}{N}\sum_i\sigma_i\Bigr)^4, 
\end{equation}
this is known to go through a first-order phase transition. Showing that would be a nice exercise where you compare the calculation with the two-body case.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I think this model doesn't have phase transition in 2d. The high temperature expansion of this model contains only a couple terms, much like the 1d classical Ising model. It's 3d, not 2d, where the KW duality takes this to the Ising model.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I think I fooled myself by confusing the classical and quantum cases... The quantum model with a transverse field is mappable to a classical Ising gauge theory in one dimensional higher space, which roughly means means 2d quantum IGT = 3d classical IGT = 3d classical Ising model.